# PowerShell form does not return expected output

Tags: forms, powershell

I am testing forms creation:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-build-a-form-in-7e343ba3

however there is no output at all when I replace code in function to:

```bsh
    $FilterCert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:LocalMachine\* -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Issuer -Like "*Daddy*" }
    $FilterCert|Format-List PSComputerName, PSParentPath, Subject, Issuer, NotBefore, NotAfter
```

funny thing is if put next code I can see output:

```bsh
    $FilterCert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:LocalMachine\* -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Issuer -Like "*Daddy*" }
    $FilterCert|Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

What kind of wizardry is this?

Cheers

Comment: Please show the surrounding code (either the event handler or the function definition + code that calls it)

Comment: Change format list to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to behave the same way as the sample, you'll need to pipe it to `Out-Gridview` like in the example `Service` function:

```bsh
Show-CertificateList
{
    $FilterCert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:LocalMachine\* -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Issuer -Like "*Daddy*" }
    $FilterCert |Select-Object PSComputerName, PSParentPath, Subject, Issuer, NotBefore, NotAfter |Out-GridView
}
```

And then update the calling event handler:

```bsh
$Okbutton.Add_Click({Show-CertificateList})
```

---

If you want regular console output as a result, use `Out-Host` in place of `Out-GridView`

Comment: Is there a way to get output in console? E.g. Transcript is empty now.

Comment: @spricer Yeah, just pipe to `Out-Host` instead of `Out-Gridview` :)